# Overlap two separate div in a page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to build a page with a button and panel. The code is built in a reusable way as this button will be used in multiple pages. However, in a particular page we have a panel displaying info and now they wanted to show this button inside panel header. Can anyone help me to merge these two divs in a separate page using CSS.

### Current:

[image]

### Desired:

[image]

Button code:

```
<div>
  <p class=""><span class="fa fa-star"></span>Mark Read</p>
</div>
```

Panel code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just move it into the heading and remove the div

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">
      <p class=""><span class="fa fa-star"></span>Mark Read</p>Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I was instructed to not to touch the panel code but overlap these two sections using pure CSS

Comment: @akrishna wow... Do you want to merge two html elements from two different pages in one new page only with CSS?

Comment: @AlbertoRhuertas, Yes if possible. I am not sure if it is even possible or not but I am tasked to implement this and looking for a help to accomplish

Comment: @akrishna If I'm right that's impossible with CSS. You can do it with javaScript.